# PyCharm has outdated SQL dialects?

Tags: postgresql, pycharm

I'm working with PostgresQL database with a python script. I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE orders SET id=%s, client=%s, contents=%s, adress=%s, detail=%s, price=%s HAVING MIN(id)
```

It works fine, but PyCharm says that "having" statement doesn't exist and i should use "where" (while "where" gives an exception in this query because I'm using "MIN"). And I have SQL dialect in PyCharm set to "PostgresQL". Any ways to fix this annoying issue?

UPD: my bad, this query isn't working. It somehow didn't throw an exception in python, but the row in database wasn't updated. Then what query should I use to update row with the least id?

Comment: Spend some time here [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

Comment: The `having` clause is invalid in an UPDATE statement in SQL. That has nothing to do with the dialect of your obfuscation layer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver didn't find what I need in docs. Do you know anything better than "execute another query before this one to get the least id and use its value next" to update row with min. id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get min(id) in the same query with either a sub-query or a CTE. Perhaps something like:

```
    update some_tbl 
       set col = 1 
     where id = (select min(id) 
                   from some_tbl
                ) ;
```

OR

```
    with lowers(mid) as 
         (select min(id) 
            from some_tbl
          ) 
    update some_tbl st
       set col = 1 
      from lowers l  
      where st.id = l.mid;
```

Comment: Thanks, first one works well, but could you please explain how the second one works? As I looked up, "with" defines a simple name for a query used next, but either I got it wrong or the second query looks confusing

Comment: Google `Postgres Update Join`. What the CTE does is create a single value input for the update.  Once the CTE is created it effectively the 'join table` on the update statement.